# Anaconda - list only package names (without version)

Tags: python, conda

I would like to create `.txt` file with all installed conda\pip packages but without version, so the list should contains `numpy` not `numpy==1.2.3`.

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: Something like `conda list | awk 'NR>3{print $1}'` ?

Comment: not sure what platform he is on

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a method in the native Conda CLI to do this.  But you can accomplish it with a Python command if you want.  This is platform independent.

```
python -c "import subprocess as s, json; j,e = s.Popen(['conda', 'list', '--json'], shell=True, stdout=s.PIPE).communicate(); list(map(lambda x: print(x['name']), json.loads(j)))" > env.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're going to involve Python code (e.g., [@James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73249098/570918)), then might as well just use the Conda API directly.

```python
from conda.core.prefix_data import PrefixData

pkgs = sorted(r.name for r in PrefixData("/path/to/env").iter_records())

print(*pkgs, sep='\n')
```

If one wants Pip-installed packages to also show up, then add a `True` as second argument to `PrefixData` method.